# How to read extended properties from Outlook contacts using EWS

Tags: outlook, exchangewebservices

I'm currently attempting to read certain properties from Outlook Contact objects through Microsoft's EWS managed API.  I retrieve these Contact objects from the `FindItems()` function.  Some of these fields are extended properties such as the `Title` or `User1` field and I'm having difficulty reading them.  At the moment, I have:

```cs
Guid propertySetId = new Guid("{00062004-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}");
ExtendedPropertyDefinition titleProp = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(propertySetId, 0x3A45, MapiPropertyType.String);
ExtendedPropertyDefinition user1Prop = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(propertySetId, 0x804F, MapiPropertyType.String);

string title, user1;
contact.TryGetProperty(titleProp, out title);
contact.TryGetProperty(user1Prop, out user1);
```

When running this, `TryGetProperty` always returns false.  I have verified that these fields are populated in Outlook for the contacts that I am searching for.

Edit:  This is how I retrieve the contact objects.

```cs
ExchangeService service = //...
Mailbox userMailbox = new Mailbox(emailAddress);
FolderId folderId = new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Contacts, userMailbox);
FindItemsResults<Item> results;
const string AQS = "Category:~>\"CategoryTag\"";
ItemView view = new ItemView(200);
results = service.FindItems(folderId, AQS, view);
foreach (var result in results)
{
    Contact contact = result as Contact;
    //...Try to read fields
}
```

Comment: You need to include the code for `Contact.Bind()` or however you are getting your `contact` field reference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to change the [`ItemView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.itemview_members%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx) to [include the properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg274394%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx#PropertyIdValues) ([`PropertySet`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.viewbase.propertyset%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx)) you wish to access.

```cs
var user1Val = string.Empty;
var user1Prop = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(DefaultExtendedPropertySet.Address, 0x804F, MapiPropertyType.String);
ExtendedPropertyDefinition[] extendedFields = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition[] { user1Prop };
PropertySet extendedPropertySet = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties, extendedFields);
ItemView view = new ItemView(200) { PropertySet = extendedPropertySet };
// ...
var title = contact.CompleteName.Title; // Title value
contact.TryGetProperty(user1Prop, out user1Val); // user field 1 value
```

Comment: I currently need to retrieve 4 different extended properties.  These are CustomerId, Title, User1, and Email1AddressType.  With your changes, I'm able to retrieve CustomerId and Email1AddressType, but Title and User1 still cannot be read.  Would you happen to know why?

Comment: Try changing the `user1Prop` to this: `ExtendedPropertyDefinition user1Prop = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(DefaultExtendedPropertySet.Address, 0x804F, MapiPropertyType.String);`

Comment: For `Title`, you should use [`Contact.CompleteName.Title`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.completename.title%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx) to retrieve the value (a first-class property).

Comment: @Klam - see edits above. This worked fine for me for retrieving the title and user fields.

Comment: Thanks a lot for everybody's help.  Everything's working now (there were also some stupid bugs on my end).

Comment: Where can I find a list of outlook properties with those "0x3A45" numbers? (MSDN always hides stuff like that from me... )

Comment: Found SOMETHING (direct download link of PDF): http://interoperability.blob.core.windows.net/files/MS-OXPROPS/[MS-OXPROPS]-080627.pdf

Comment: We are also running into same problem.
This was not working with:

var extendedProp = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(DefaultExtendedPropertySet.Address, 0x3673, MapiPropertyType.String);

But, following worked for us.
var extendedProp = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(0x3673, MapiPropertyType.String);