# Exchange Web Services API - Contact.ItemProperties Equivalent

Tags: .net, vb.net, vb6, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I have an old VB6 application that creates Outlook contacts using MAPI and I am in the process of converting it to VB .NET 2010.

The VB6 application allows me to access properties by name using the `ItemProperties` property, for example:

```
objContact.ItemProperties(strPropertyName) = "Accountant"
```

I can see `ItemProperties` in the [extended property list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg274394%28v=exchg.80%29) but I cannot work out how to access it.  Other [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10385948/how-to-read-extended-properties-from-outlook-contacts-using-ews) show how to access extended properties for existing contacts but I am trying to create new a contact.

Is it possible to set properties dynamically as you could in MAPI?  If not I will end up with a very large CASE statement i.e.

```
Select Case strPropertyName
 Case "JobTitle"
  ...
 Case "Title"
  ...
End Select
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example of creating a [`Contact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.contact%28v=exchg.80%29) in EWS and using [`ExtendedProperties`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.item.extendedproperties%28v=exchg.80%29). You need to make use of the [`SetExtendedProperty`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee693716%28v=exchg.80%29) method, passing in the appropriate [`ExtendedPropertyDefinition`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.extendedpropertydefinition%28v=exchg.80%29).

```cs
var titleDef = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(0x3A45, MapiPropertyType.String);

Contact contact = new Contact(service);
contact.GivenName = "George";
contact.Surname = "Washington";
contact.FileAsMapping = FileAsMapping.SurnameSpaceGivenName;
contact.CompanyName = "U.S.A";
contact.PhoneNumbers[PhoneNumberKey.BusinessPhone] = "555-234-1231";
contact.EmailAddresses[EmailAddressKey.EmailAddress1] = "asdfas@dafasd.com";
contact.EmailAddresses[EmailAddressKey.EmailAddress1].Name = "G. Washington";
contact.SetExtendedProperty(titleDef, "President");
contact.Save();
var contactID = contact.Id;
```